# How to remove b' and ' when I encode a String in Python 3.8.0?

Tags: python, udp

I am working with UDP in python 3.8.0, but I am having a problem with my message, once the socket doesn't allow a string, I have to convert the string to binary, so I used `message.encode()`, but it comes with an additional b' and ' at the end of the message, how can I remove them?

My code:

```
import socket
import sys
import config

MY_IP = config.myIP
OTHER_IP = config.otherIp
PORT_NUMBER = config.port_number

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

server_address = (MY_IP, PORT_NUMBER)
message = input("Write a message: ").encode( )
print("Message: ", message)
```

The output of the result you can see below:

```
Write a message: a
Message:  b'a'
```

Is there another way to change string to binary?

A new python learner thanks you.

Comment: May be help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: There is no actual `b` character, that is just how python represents `bytes` objects to distinguish them from `str` objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b'...'` is just how python represents the bytes type. For example:

```py
my_string = "This is my string."
type(my_string) # str type

encoded_string = my_string.encode()
type(encoded_string) # bytes type, when printing represented by leading b
```

You can convert a bytes type back to a str using the built-in `.decode()` method:

```py
decoded_string = encoded_string.decode()
type(decoded_string) # str type
```

**Extra:**

You also are able to specify the encoding charset used by `.encode()` and `.decode()`:

```py
hello_encoded = "Hello".encode("ascii") # bytes type
hello_decoded = hello_encoded.decode("ascii") # str type
```

When encoding with utf-8 you can write all sorts of fancy characters (those are not possible to encode with ascii, would throw an error):

```py
fancy_chars_encoded = "© ½ £ 4²".encode("utf-8")
fancy_chars_decoded = fancy_chars_encoded.decode("utf-8")
```

Also, `utf-8` is the default charset used when no charset is passed to `.encode()` or `.decode()`.

Comment: This is not a answer for OP.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You did it correct. And this `b` only means that this string is byte. This is not a part of your variable. For example:

```
>>> a = "abc".encode()
>>> print(a)
b'abc'
>>> print(len(a))
3 # not 6
>>> print(a[0])
'a' # not b
```

Comment: I need to send the message to another computer using the UDP connection (`sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)`), won't this b' matter at all? Is it just some kind of sign?

Comment: @Codewraith no, **there is no `b`** in those bytes.

Comment: No, this ```b``` dont matter. It is only a way to python show you that type of your variable is bytes. If my answer helped you, please mark it as answer.